# What is the difference between executable and relocatable in elf format?

Tags: elf

What is the difference between executable file in elf format and relocatable file in elf format?

Answer (score 19):

as you know every compiled executable file is a binary file with address relative and absolute, so  relocatable format is a format in which function and other symbols still have there names definition in other word functions and variables are not bound to any specific address. Instead, the addresses are still symbols

look :

```bash
unix > gcc -c main.c
unix > readelf --symbols main.o
Num:     Value   Size     Type      Bind       Vis     Ndx  Name
  0:  00000000      0   NOTYPE     LOCAL   DEFAULT     UND
  1:  00000000      0   FILE       LOCAL   DEFAULT     ABS  main.c
  2:  00000000      0   OBJECT    GLOBAL   DEFAULT     3    buf
  3:  00000000      0   OBJECT    GLOBAL   DEFAULT     1    main

unix > gcc main.c -o main
unix > readelf --symbols main
Num:     Value   Size     Type      Bind       Vis     Ndx  Name
 53:  08048460      2     FUNC    GLOBAL   DEFAULT     13   __libc_csu_fini
 54:  08048462      0     FUNC    GLOBAL   HIDDEN      13   __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
 55:  0804a018      4     OBJECT  GLOBAL   DEFAULT     13   bufp0
```

do you see what i'm talking about

most of the time we use them as static library

look to the example here :

```c
#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H
int add(int a, int b);
#endif

/* math_test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main(void)
{
  int result = add(1, 2);
  printf("result: %d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

try to compile it

```
unix > gcc math_test.c -o math_test
/tmp/cclRibQq.o: In function `main':
math_test.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `add'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

that due to function `add` has no body in `math_test.c` so we can do the flowing:

```c
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

then compile it as a relocatable using gcc

```
unix > gcc -c math.c                      # Create relocatable obj file (math.o)
unix > readelf -h math.o | grep Type      # Read math.o with readelf
Type:            REL (Relocatable file)   # and verify its type
```

then  you can link it with linker like this :

```
unix > gcc math_test.c math.o -o math_test
unix > ./math_test
result: 3
```

a great article about the difference between executable file in elf format and relocatable file in elf format you can find [here](https://carsontang.github.io/unix/2013/06/01/guide-to-object-file-linking/)

Comment: Please summarize it here, so that the information is preserved if the link dies.

Comment: @sorak can you take a look and till me if any other thing is wrong to fix it thank you

Comment: Good work, thank you. I added syntax highlighting. Check out how that works.

Answer (score 16):

As it can be seen in the image below, relocatable ELF goes as the input to the linker, whereas the executable ELF is the product of the linker.

[image: Freescale SC100 development tools example diagram]

Answer (score 7):

ELF executable, as we can understand from its name, is a file that can be executed. This file can be generated from C code for example.

The process of relocation is fixing the addresses of labels and symbols which were created in the code. For example, if you write a program in assembly language and you look at the listing file of your source code, you'll find some places where [00000000] is written instead of a label mentioned at this line. This zeroes mean that he linker uses relocation in order to fix the address the its future value.

Answer (score 7):

Relocatable doesn't have any Load address its only binary code sequence with offset (for example offset related to main() func). But,executable file having load address not just offset related to any of the function.

one more fundamental difference between them is Executable have bootstrap application but relocatable doesn't have it.